# Best way to display 60,000 records on a php webpage

Tags: php, web-services, web-applications

I am looking to display 60,000 records on a webpage with php pulling the records from a mysql database on localhost. These 60,000 records may change depending on the data input.

The records have 5 text fields and due to the sheer number of records, a significant time is taken to send the data from the mysql server to the web browser. Even on a localhost, the time taking is around 15 seconds. During this time, the page is empty.

I would like to seek professional opinion on how to either to
1. display the data in an alternative method, (which I'm not sure what method) or
2. hasten the sending of data from mysql server to the web browser using caching technology like memcache.

In the end i will be deploying the application on the internet where the lag would be immensely unacceptable (i.e. > 15 seconds).

Thank you and Best Regards!

Comment: all at once? how about pagination?

Comment: don't do that ever ... your browser **100%** will hang

Comment: @ajreal Pfft. Get a "real" browser ;-) However, 60k *raw* records is hardly ideal for any *human* consumption -- even without resource issues.

Comment: Provide the user with some way to filter the data so they receive only an interesting subset of that. Nobody can reasonably browse through 60,000 records -- even giving each record a 1-second glance would take more than 2 full days of full-time work.

Comment: Memcache is also a bad idea for something like this.  memcached institutes a 1MB limit on value size.  To store a recordset of 60k records, you'd need to tweak that.  Or create 60k keys.  Try pagination.

Comment: hi luckytaxi, I'm glad your cab stopped by. I was thinking about pagination but not sure how i should go around to implement that.

Comment: Hi pst, you're absolutely right!

Comment: Hi Jerry Coffin, Hmm... i would have to think about this a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Chris Henry, I hadn't know about the 1MB limit on memcache. I was hoping to use it more but now i need to look into its limitations and use it in an appropriate manner now.

Comment: May I ask why you felt it was necessary to show 60,000 records on one screen? I am honestly curious.

Comment: Hi Andrew Heath, actually I have no idea on the best way to display the 60,000 records. I thought I should start out with the easiest solution, then further improve on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest trying AJAX pagination. No user will be able to see and analyze 60k records at one time. You can have the php display the first `x` (however many fit on the average screen or two) records to fill 2-3 pages, and have JavaScript listen for a scroll change. If a user starts scrolling down, have it automatically query the next `y` records, and add them to the display list. Possibly also removing the records from the top of the list.

Also, adding some quick-jump links or a search feature could help, as you wouldn't want to scroll down 60k records to make changes.

This will *significantly* lighten the server and client load, as it would only have to serve up a couple hundred records at a time.

Comment: Follow some other tips also! don't try try to show all the pagelinks provide a next button which will be more tactical!

Comment: Thanks Harish! I'm looking into ajax tutorials to perform preloading of data as well.

Answer (score 2):

### DataTable

You should have a look at [YUI's DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/datatable/). You should hook the datatable up to [autocomplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/autocomplete/). There is also an example how they did it in [YUI2](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_autocomplete.html)(help) but YUI3 is a lot faster.

### Caching

Caching is also important. You say you could use memcached so that is very good. I am a big fan of redis(But both will work, but the nice thing is that redis is I think [better suited for autocomplete](http://antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html)). There is even a free plan of [Redis To go](http://redistogo.com/).

Comment: Hey Alfred, This is great stuff! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Another important tip is to make sure you are getting your data as you want it displayed from the database. In other words if there is any calculation or processing that you have to do, avoid doing it in PHP code during loops. Use SQL functions to process data, name fields, etc. Databases are good at that sort of thing. Of course this may or may not apply to exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Hi Excalibur, you're absolutely right! I'm not intending to use PHP for any heavy weight lifting. The processing should be performed in the DB.